# Excel Number Formatting - not to be carried into copied cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

Open a new sheet and type in any cell (28.33943576)
Change the format to 4 decimal places to show (28.3394)
Copy the cell into a new cell as value only (copies 28.3394)

Now if you click on the copied cell, look at the function bar above. It says 28.33943576, which is the original number.  How can I get this to only read 28.3394 in the formula bar?

Answer (score 1):

Formatting only changes how the value is **displayed** in a cell, not the actual value that appears in the Formula Bar.  To change the actual value:

> =ROUND(A1,4)

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want to truncate the number, there is a setting in the options menu called 'Precision as displayed'. But be very careful with this. Once used it permanently truncates numbers. It should warrant a warning on the spreadsheet so that users know this is happening.